# 'Point of time' vs 'Period of time'

Tags: present-perfect

I am not a native English speaker and in my country my teacher used to ask students to translate our native language into English and vice-versa. That's when, I encountered this question for the very first time. My teacher emphasized on the usage of 'since' in the following example which I could never reconcile myself to.
I have some questions regarding the following sentences:

1. *I've been watching TV **for** last two days.*
2. *I've been watching TV **since** last two days.*

Which sentence above is grammatical?

Am I correct if I say: the expression "two days" refers to a "period of time" so use: *for*, but the "last two days" refers to "point of time" so use: *since*?

I read the following explanation on [answers.com](http://www.answers.com/Q/For_last_two_months_or_since_last_two_months_which_is_correct?#slide=5)

> Since last two months", that one is correct. When you are talking about a period of time, you have to use *since*, because it's a grammatical word used to indicate that a situation has continued from a particular time or event in the past.

The explanation provided by that website further adds to my misery!
Please help me understand it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please say where you read these examples, (the source) state its name and, if possible, include a link. Or whether you invented these examples yourself.

Comment: The use of "since" is correct if you are referring to a point in time.  "Last two days" is not a point in time, though.  "Two days ago" is a point in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is really correct, since you have to say "**the** last two days", but the first one is closer to being correct.

"two days" is a period of time, but "the last two days" is also a period of time, so you would say "*for* the last two days".  If you mean "beginning at a point in time two days ago", you would say "*since* two days ago".

Reference: [FOR and SINCE for Time](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_for-since.htm)

Comment: how about this http://www.answers.com/Q/For_last_two_months_or_since_last_two_months_which_is_correct?#slide=5 ?

Comment: @kilimanjaro - The answer given at answers.com is incorrect.  Literally saying "since last two months" is wrong.